# Syntax help for using bitwise to removing decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript

trying to format variables as they get updated. I would like to do this by using the [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).  I cant seem to understadn the syntax.

Currently the numbers come in like `5.2342340990843`  at max i would love them to be 2 decimals deep max.
[example code](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/IahFy)

```
var app = angular.module('morningharwoodApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.squares = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    if ($window.DeviceMotionEvent != undefined) {
    $window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
    //wan tto make this a 32bit integer by using pipe 0 however it's erroring out
      $scope.acceleration = {
        x: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x*10 | 0,  
        y: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y*10 | 0,  
        z: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z*10 | 0
      };

      $scope.$digest();

    };
  }
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="morningharwoodApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="icon-wrapper">
        <div class="icons" ng-repeat="(key, val) in squares">   
          <p>X : <span>{{acceleration.x}}</span></p>
          <p>Y : <span>{{acceleration.y}}</span></p>
          <p>Z : <span>{{acceleration.z}}</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use bitwise operators, there is a method [**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) that does this. It allows you to specify the number of digits after the decimal

```
var d = 5.231579843214564;
var fixed = d.toFixed(2);
console.log(fixed);
//outputs: 5.23
```

Note this creates a string representation, if you want it back to a number instead of a string jst prepend a `+` operator to the front

```
var fixed = +d.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Are you meaning to just have the integer part and not the decimal part?

Comment: yeah  just an integer is all i need.

Comment: ok well your wording made it sound like you wanted it to, two decimal places... then in what way is it erroring out?

Comment: arg it wasnt erroring out.  I'm dumb your answer is still what I'll use